# Can i use column 1 as the key-column and x as data point number per key?

Tags: gnuplot

I have data like:

```
A 1
B 2
C 1
D 3
A 4
B 3
C 2
D 1
```

Where the first column will repeat a small number of `key` names. But it's a variable number and the values can change from run to run.

Is there a `plot` definition i can use that'll use the first column as they `key`, plot the second column as `y` and plot `x` from the data point number **per `key`**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK this is not possible. Gnuplot  can do some sort of arithmetic but not of this kind. Either you tweak the program that exports this kind of data format to something gnuplot can handle or write a little script that does the same trick for you.

If I understood you correctly this python script should do convert the data into something gnuplot can handle:

```
#data = <read your data file>
Content = data.split("\n")
Dict = dict()
for l in Content:
    Line = l.split(" ")
    if not Line[0] in Dict:
        Dict[Line[0]] = int(Line[1])
    else:
        Dict[Line[0]] += int(Line[1])

file = open("Output.data", "w") 
for (key, value) in Dict.items():
    file.write(key + " " + str(value) + "\n")
file.close()
```

Comment: Thanks for confirming my assumption and for the script. I already have some processes in place to do the same but i was hoping someone would point out something i've missed in the docs :)